# Binding fails on big data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, binding

I created an app with real time filtering and sorting (the list changed dynamically when text in a textbox changed). I used a ListBox bound to an ObservableCollection and later to a List. It worked fine for small data, but when I used like 1000 items it failed.

I used an **in place** QuickSort for sorting and Visibility property for filtered items. I guessed it would be best for performance reasons.

First I tried with ObservableCollection bound to a ListBox. When I typed text fast it threw an exception ( Layout cycle detected ).

Than I tried with a List as ItemsSource. After sorting/filtering was done I fired NotifyPropertyChanged("MyList"). There was no exception but when the filer phrase resulted in only a **few  visible** items. It loaded VERY slow.

I ended up doing something I don't like, because it looks really amateurish.

```
Data.ApplyFiltersSorting();
ItemsListBox.ItemsSource = Data.MyItems.Where(a => a.Visibility == Visibility.Visible);
```

Which actually works fast and causes no errors.

Can somebody tell me what could have possibly been wrong in my earlier attempts and also what's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `CollectionViewSource` for Sorting and Filtering?

Geoff Hudik does something similar here: http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2010/10/14/wp7-in-app-searching-filtering.html